# Messing around with the $\cos$ & $\sin$ relation with $\pi$. Apparently got wrong.

Tags: limits, trigonometry, pi

So the $\sin$ relation with $\pi$ is;

$$\pi  =\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n\cdot\sin(\frac{180}{n}) \tag{Eq. 01}\label{1} $$

And the $\cos$ one is;

$$\pi = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})} \tag{Eq. 02}\label{2}$$

So from these two, we can get;

\begin{align}
n*\sin(\frac{180}{n}) & = n\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})} \\
\sin(\frac{180}{n}) & = \sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})} \\ 
\sin^2(\frac{180}{n}) & = 2(1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})) \\
\frac{\sin^2(\frac{180}{n})}{1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})} & = 2 \\ 
\frac{1-\cos^2(\frac{180}{n})}{1-\cos(\frac{180}{n})} & = 2 \\
1+\cos(\frac{180}{n}) & = 2 \\
\cos(\frac{180}{n}) & = 1 \\
\end{align}

This isn't obviously true. So what's the problem here?

Comment: They are only equal in the limit as $n\to\infty$. Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos{(180/n)}=\cos{(0)}=1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Oh I see it now, big thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same as the following argument
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2n=0$$
$$\implies\frac1n=\frac2n$$
$$\implies1=2$$
Why would the first equality imply the second?

Comment: In other words

$$\lim\limits_{n} a_n = \lim\limits_{n} b_n$$

does *not* imply $a_n = b_n$.